# C++ Raytracer - Only one object appearing in scene

Tags: c++, object, scene, raytracing

I am using a raytracer to render a Sphereflake, but I am having trouble trying to have more than object appear in the scene. In the scene below I am just trying to test out having two spheres in a scene, but for some reason only ever one sphere appears in the scene, and usually its the sphere with the largest radius.

Another peculiar thing is, even though there is a camera set in the scene, it seems as though the output window always shows the predominant object at the centre ((0,0) with screen coordinates between [-1,-1]->[1,1]) rather than in relevance to the camera coordinate space.

I am unsure if it is a parent hierarchy problem or how I'm rendering the objects, but any insight into why the problem is persisting would be greatly appreciated.

main.cpp (creates scenes renders objects)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp> 

#include <Raytracer/Raytracer.h>

using namespace glm;
using namespace Raytracer;
using namespace Raytracer::Scenes;
using namespace Raytracer::Objects;

/**
 * Places a few spheres in the scene and adds some lights.
 *
 * @param scene The scene
 */
Scene *BuildScene(int depth, float aspect)
{
    const int materialCount = 6;

    vec3 colors[materialCount] =
    {
      vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
      vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
      vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
      vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
      vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
      vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
    };

    Material *materials[materialCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < materialCount; i++)
    {
        materials[i] = new Material();
        if (materials[i] == NULL)
            return NULL;

        vec3 ambient = colors[i] * 0.01f;
        materials[i]->SetAmbient(ambient);
        materials[i]->SetDiffuse(colors[i]);
        materials[i]->SetShininess(25.0f);
    }

    if (depth <= 0)
        return NULL;

    // Create the scene.
    Scene *scene = new Scene();
    if (scene == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Sphere * s1 = new Sphere(0.33f, materials[5]);
    s1->SetPosition(vec3(5.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f));
    Sphere * s2 = new Sphere(0.33f, materials[1]);
    s2->SetPosition(vec3((5.0f, 0.33f, -2.0f));

    s1->AddChild(s2);

  // Create a light.
  Light *light = new PointLight(vec3(10.0f));
  if (light == NULL)
  {
    delete scene;
    return NULL;
  }

  light->SetPosition(vec3(-5.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f));
  scene->AddChild(light);

  // Create a camera.
  Camera *camera = new Camera(vec3(-2.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
    vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), Camera::DefaultFov, aspect);

  scene->AddChild(s1);

  if (camera == NULL)
  {
    delete scene;
    return NULL;
  }
  scene->AddChild(camera);
  scene->SetActiveCamera(camera);

  return scene;
}

/**
 * Renders the scene and saves the result to a BMP file.
 *
 * @param fileName The name of the file
 * @param width The image width
 * @param height The image height
 */
void Render(const char *fileName, int width, int height)
{
  if (fileName == NULL || width <= 0 || height <= 0)
    return;

  SimpleRenderer renderer;

  renderer.SetAccelerator(new SimpleAccelerator());
  renderer.SetIntegrator(new PhongIntegrator());

  puts("Generiere Szene...");
  Scene *scene = BuildScene(3, (float)width / height);
  if (scene == NULL)
    return;

  puts("Rendere Bild...");
  Image *image = renderer.Render(*scene, width, height);
  if (image != NULL)
  {
    puts("Speichere Ergebnis...");
    image->SaveBMP(fileName, 2.2f);
    delete image;
  }

  delete scene;
}

/**
 * The main program
 */
int main()
{
  Render("image.bmp", 512, 512);
  return 0;
}
```

example of a scene with two spheres as stated above with `s1.radius = 0.33f & s2.radius = 0.33f`

[scene 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVD0n.png)

another example of a scene with two spheres with `s1.radius = 0.33f & s2.radius = 1.0f`

[scene 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCydW.png)

As you can see, it seems the camera is invalid as a point of perspective, as no matter what the position of the sphere is, the only difference is its lighting, but it will always be at the centre of the display window

Comment: `vec4 pos = vec4(s2->GetPosition(), 1.0f) * s2->GetTransformation() * RotationY(30);` Is doing a left-side multiplication really what you want here? Typically, 3d transforms are `matrix * vec`, not the other way around.

Comment: apologies, that was just test code, its really not a wanted result, I originally had the position to be of radius length away from s1, so that the two spheres would be in the scene touching, yet nothing seems to work as even still only ever one sphere appears in the scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since s2 is attached as a child of s1, it's being drawn 5 units further down the X axis than s1:

```
s2->SetPosition(vec3((5.0f, 0.33f, -2.0f));
...
s1->AddChild(s2);
```

And since your camera is looking down the positive x axis:

```
Camera *camera = new Camera(vec3(-2.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f), 
    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), Camera::DefaultFov, aspect);
```

s2 is simply being drawn behind s1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I took what you said into consideration and set the positon of s2 to `s2->SetPosition(vec3(0.0f, 0.33f, 0.0f));` and still only one of the objects is appearing, I waas hoping that it would now appear on top of s1, but still nothing

Comment: One thing though, if this was the case, then if the second object is drawn with a bigger radius and placed further down the x-axis, then it should still appear behind the first sphere, but no matter what I set the positions to, only ever 1 sphere appears in the scene

Comment: any idea why only one object ever shows, I've gone through the function again and again and can't wrack my head to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was not a problem with my scene builder, but how the child/parent inherritance works in another class `SceneObject*`. Anyway, I fixed the AddChild function and now the code now works with the camera perspective and with mulitple items in the scene